# Calculating the 'most recently used' of a django ManyToMany relation

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a simple Tag model that many other models have a ManyToMany relationship to. The requirement has come up to be able to query/show the most recently used Tags in the system, across all entities that have Tags.

I can add a `used_at` attribute to the Tag model, and I could order on that.  But obviously, the Tag model doesn't get modified when something else just references it, so an `auto_now` on that attribute won't help me.

Without the use of a `through` model (which could have an `auto_now_add` on it), and without performing any invisible (non-django) magic directly in the DB with triggers, is there a sensible way to update the Tag's timestamp whenever a model is saved that references it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [m2m_changed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) signal

From docs:

> Sent when a ManyToManyField is changed on a model instance. Strictly
>   speaking, this is not a model signal since it is sent by the
>   ManyToManyField, but since it complements the pre_save/post_save and
>   pre_delete/post_delete when it comes to tracking changes to models, it
>   is included here

Comment: So I had thought about signals, but I'd need a signal connection for every model that is taggable, right? And if new models decide to add a `tags` attribute, but forget to set up a signal connection, then it won't get updated ...